# Django Sum of foreing key values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two Django models. `Client` and `Group` with relation one-to-many (Client can have assigned multiple groups). The model `Group` contains three integer fields `sc_done`, `sc_analyze` and `sc_error`. What I'm trying to do is to create Django query which returns top 10 `Clients` with the highest number of sum `sc_done`, `sc_analyze` and `sc_error` among all their groups. The models look like:

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    sc_done = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sc_analyze = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sc_error = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

For example, if `client-1` is part of two groups: `group-1`, `group-2`, the query would return something like: `{'client': 'client-1', 'sc_count': X}` where X is sum of `sc_done`, `sc_analyze` and `sc_error` of `group-1` and `group-2` together.

Not sure if this question is understandable, please ask if any clarification needed.

Comment: Share your models here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Client.objects.values(
    'name'
).annotate(
    sc_done_sum=Sum('group__sc_done'),
    sc_analyze_sum=Sum('group__sc_analyze'),
    sc_error_sum=Sum('group__sc_error'),
    sc_count=F('sc_done_sum')+F('sc_analyze_sum')+F('sc_error_sum'),
    client=F('name'),
).values(
    'client',
    'sc_count',
).order_by('-sc_count')[:10]
```

Expected result:

```
[{'client': 'client-1', 'sc_count': 100},
 ...
 {'client': 'client-2', 'sc_count': 90}]
```